# Set field value - only if empty - in a Marketo Form

Tags: javascript, marketo

My team wants to set up a master Marketo form for landing pages hosted on our own site.  They set up the form with hidden fields and added instructions in Marketo, and I have provided a way for them to assign campaign ID, asset and the redirect url as needed. This works by generating the following code:

```
<script src="//app-sj05.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_ourFormID"></form>
<script>
        MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sj05.marketo.com", "ourID", ourFormID, function(form) {
            // Set values in hidden fields to determine campaign and asset to serve
            form.vals({
                "Campaign_Id__c":"assignedCampaignID", 
                 "Campaign_Asset__c":"assignedCampaignAsset"
            });
            // Override redirect URL set in Marketo
            form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl) {
                location.href = "redirectURL";
                // Return false to prevent the submission handler continuing with its own processing
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

The next step is to assign the campaign iD only if it's not already included in the referring url.  So I need some sort of if/then statement that looks at the hidden campaign ID to see if there's a value - and assign a value only if there is not.  I'm not a javascript master by any stretch, and I'm not sure what is the best method for the Marketo API.  Can someone help me with this last bit of if/else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with marketo forms - could you log what 'form' looks like, and what properties you want to modify?

Answer (score 0):

If you call form.vals() with no arguments it will return all of the values of the form in an object.  So it would look like this:

```
if (!form.vals().Campaign_Id__c){
    form.vals({"Campaign_Id__c": myValue});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sanford Whiteman via Marketo Support Forum, this did the job:

```
<script src="//app-sj05.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_ourFormID"></form>
<script>
    MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sj05.marketo.com", "ourID", ourFormID, function(form) {
        // Set values in hidden field to determine asset to serve
        form.vals({ 
            "Campaign_Asset__c":"assignedCampaignAsset"
        });
        // Check to see if referring url set campaign ID, if not set value in hidden field
        if( !form.getValues()['Campaign_Id__c'] ) {
            form.setValues({
                "Campaign_Id__c":"assignedCampaignID"
            })
        }
        // Override redirect URL set in Marketo
        form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl) {
            location.href = "redirectURL";
            // Return false to prevent the submission handler continuing with its own processing
            return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```